# Wordpress на главной страницы отображает meta последней записи

Tags: wordpress

Добрый день! wordpress почему-то на главное отображает метаданные последней записи. При шаринге главной ссылки в соцсети отображает превьюшку последней записи и тайтлы последней записи. Не могу понять в чем дело. 
Вывожу мета таким образом:

```html
<meta property="og:url"           content="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" />
<meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
<meta property="og:title"         content="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" />
<?php if(has_post_thumbnail()):
    $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
?>
<meta property="og:image"         content="<?php echo $url; ?>" />
<?php else:
    $theme = wp_get_theme();
    $screenshot_url = esc_url( $theme->get_screenshot() );
?>
<meta property="og:image"         content="<?php echo $screenshot_url; ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Скорее всего, главный цикл сделан неправильно, в конце нет `wp_reset_postdata();` А еще из вопроса непонятно, а данные какой записи вы там хотели бы увидеть.

Comment: Хотелось бы, чтоб отображались мета прописанные для сайта в настройках.

Comment: И какое отношение к ним имеют `the_permalink()`, `get_the_title()`?

Comment: Получается нужно добавить условие? Если открыта главная, то показывать одни мета, а если открыта запись, то другие? Правда не совсем понимаю как это сделать

Comment: Поставьте плагин Yoast SEO и не мучайтесь